# NSDictionary in tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary

i have a NSDictionary of this type :

```
" **********" =     (
    "20110330 7Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 8Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 9CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 AHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 B10CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 **CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    ""
);
" 2012" =     (
    "20110330 Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    ""
);
" just for the test" =     (
    "20110330 AHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 BHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 1Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 2Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 3Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 4Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 5CHuge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 6Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    ""
);
```

i want to do a tableView with " ******* , 2012 , just for the test " the titles of the differents section. And the content "20110330 7Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 8Huge Sandstorm over niger",
    "20110330 9CHuge Sandstorm over niger....." For each section.

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the sub elements within each key are NSArrays, then you can just return the number of keys in the dictionary as the number of sections, the actual key for the title for each section, and then for the number of rows in each section return the number of elements in the array under that particular key

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [myDictionary count];//returns the number of key/object pairs
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    return [allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *curArray = [myDictionary objectForKey:curKey];

    return [curArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //normal cell acquisition code

    NSArray *allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *curArray = [myDictionary objectForKey:curKey];
    NSString *curValue = [curArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //Do something with the string
}
```

Comment: thanks the sections and title are good in my test but the content is not write in my tableView.

where must i use curValue variable ?

Comment: `curValue` is what you would set the cell's text to display as.  something like `cell.textLabel.text = curValue;`